# How do I select a cell referenced by a variable on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reference

This is what I have so far. I need a sub to copy a group of cells and paste their values on the next empty cell available. The error I'm getting is in selecting that first available cell. Any thoughts?

```
Dim workline As Integer
Sub Test()
With ActiveSheet
workline = 11
    While .Cells(workline, 2) <> Empty
    workline = workline + 1
    Wend
End With
    Range("B3:CH9").Select
    Selection.Copy



     range(workline,2) .Select



Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Message = MsgBox("Data copied succesfully", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Aecon Mining")
End Sub`
```

Comment: Found the answer it was ActiveSheet.Cells(workline, 2).Select

Answer (score 4):

Not tested in Excel, but should work, or at least pointing you to the right direction:

```
Range("B3:CH9").Copy
Range("B2").end(xlDown).offset(1,0).paste 'first available cell
```

And stop using those .Select and selection everywhere, they are a total waste of time.